# Azure - deploying from Bitbucket

Tags: git, deployment, azure

I have a website hosted on Windows Azure, and I set it up quite a few months ago to automatically deploy when I push to a specific branch on Bitbucket - as per these instructions:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/#header-3

This was working fine last time I made any changes to the site (which was Nov 24th 2012). I've just pushed another change, and it hasn't been deployed. Going back through the settings again, it looks like the functionality has been removed from the Azure dashboard. I no longer see the option "Set up Git publishing" in the quick glance section.

I've Googled to see if I can find any reference to this functionality being removed, but I've had no luck. Does anyone know why suddenly I can no longer deploy from my Bitbucket account, or no longer have the functionality at all in the Azure control panel?

Comment: should still be working, in fact they have added more functionality.  You should see a wizard dialogue http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/03/18/windows-azure-new-hadoop-service-html5-js-cors-phonegap-mercurial-and-dropbox-support.aspx

Comment: Did you get this working in the end?

Comment: @Dashu No, I ended up just adding another remote repository for Azure, and pushing to that when I wanted to deploy. I didn't actually notice levelnis had replied - I'll give his suggestion a go some point this week, and update this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably lost the post commit hook between Azure and Bitbucket. I found this happening on occasion for me as well. If you have a look on the Services page within your Bitbucket repository settings there should be a POST hook to Azure. I would remove the hook if it's there and then clear out the deployments folder within your Azure site to reset it.

If you FTP into your site and clear out the deployments folder (there'll be a bunch of folders named as guids that represent the deployments that have happened) and then go back and refresh the dashboard page you should see the option to set up Git publishing appear again.

Comment: Hi. I've just tried this, and it didn't work. The option didn't re-appear.

Comment: Interesting - it's a bit of a pain, but you could try removing the site and starting over. I had issues with one site that I had set up and creating a new site didn't cause the problems to re-appear. We never got to the bottom of the issues with the problem site and just chalked it up to teething troubles with Azure websites.

Comment: I've now just got it set up as a separate remote Git repo which I push to the Azure repo when I want to go live, and Bitbucket otherwise. Git's that flexible with remote repos and branches anyway, that it's not a huge change in deployment workflow.

Comment: Bit rubbish that you can't just push to Bitbucket and have it deploy automatically though. Still, if you're happy with the way it's working then it's all good

Comment: I have a dev branch and a live branch. Both have remote tracking branches (dev links to Bitbucket, live links to Azure). So as far as my workflow is concerned, I'm literally just pushing my live branch, and git does the rest for me. So it's no extra work at all. The only downside is that I have to set up the two remote repos on all my machines (which is just my main PC and laptop, so no biggie, as it's a one time setup). Thanks for you help though - will update this thread if I ever find out what happened! :)